# Como informar login e senha para acessar uma api com vueJs e axios?

Tags: vue.js, axios

Estou recebendo um erro: `Request failed with status code 401` ao tentar se conectar a uma api usando vue e axios, eu sou completamente novo em consumir api, no caso ela é uma Django Rest, qual a sintaxe correta para informar o login e senha usando axios, talvez seja este trexo

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
    data() {
        return {

            errored:false
        }
    },
    mounted() {

        axios
            .post('https://xxx.com.br/api/', {}, {
                auth: {
                    username: 'teste',
                    password: 'teste123'
                }
            })
            .then(response => (this.info = response))
            .catch(error => {
                console.log("o catch pegou " +error);
                this.errored = true;
            })
            .finally(() =>{
                this.loading = false;
            });

    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Se o **console.log()** traz os dados corretamente, a requisição está sendo feita corretamente, o erro **`401`** geralmente é provocado quando não se tem permissão para acesso ou por algum motivo a permissão e os dados de permissão não conferem.

Comment: O status http 401 significa que não foi autorizado. Você precisa ver como funciona essa API para a autenticação (ler a documentação dela). Geralmente, você precisa **enviar** algo para **reconhecer que você é você**, e para isso é necessário ser **POST** e ver se precisa enviar login e senha, ou então apenas um token de autenticação. Por exemplo, algumas API você primeiro se autentica em outra URL na página de login e é devolvido um **TOKEN**, e posteriormente em cada requisição para a API, você precisa enviar esse TOKEN (como se fosse um login e senha).

Comment: Provalvelmente preciso enviar login e senha porque me enviaram estes, mas a questão é essa qual a sintaxe para enviar o login e senha usando axios/vue?

É um teste que me enviaram pra vaga de uma empresa, inclusive acho que não há uma documentação para consumir a api, mas eu acabei de solicitar a documentação da api ao recrutador.